# how to emulate pressing the Enter key

Tags: windows-7, command-line

System: Windows 7 64 bit. Interface: cmd.exe.

I need to run an executable in batch. When run in interactive mode, the executable asks for a sequence of commands (each one of course followed by the Enter key) and finally it asks you to press the Enter key to continue (and finish). This last step is blocking me. I managed to write the following:

```
mycode.exe < batch.txt
```

where the file `batch.txt` has the following content.

```
bar.out
28
foo.in
summary.out
```

The four lines contain the correct commands `mycode.exe`. The problem is that I don't know how to send the "Enter" command to `mycode.exe`...is there a way?

**EDIT**: maybe I'm not using the right words. I'm not a programmer nor a computer scientist. I'll try with a practical example: if I open a `cmd` prompt and write (followed by Enter)

```
D:\test> mycode.exe
```

I get

```
Enter output file name:
```

I write

```
bar.out
```

Then I get a list of options among which to choose, and the prompt:

```
Enter option from menu:
```

I enter

```
28
```

I get

```
Enter input file name:
```

I enter

```
foo.in
```

I get

```
Enter summary file:
```

I enter

```
summary.out
```

Then the code sends a long output to screen, and finally it writes:

```
Press ENTER to continue
```

If, instead than running it from the command line, I use

```
mycode.exe < batch.txt
```

I get a Fortran error, so I was thinking that maybe I would need to include the equivalent of pressing the ENTER key, inside my file `batch.txt`.

Comment: This won't work unless `mycode.exe` is designed to read values from the command line.

Comment: yes! It's exactly what it is designed for. That's the problem: it's a command line tool, which for some reasons (I can go in details if you want, but be warned: boring :) I need to "fool" into running in batch. The problem is, I don't know how to give the "Enter" command from a text file...

Comment: @DavidPostill - If the program reads from the standard input stream, it will work.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That's not clear from the question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin you think it should work, even if there is no command corresponding to the Enter key? Because apparently it's not working now. I'm adding a few details to the questions, maybe it will make it more clear.

Comment: @DeltaIV What happens if you add an extra blank line to `batch.txt`?

Comment: @DeltaIV this might be off interest of you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038282/press-keyboard-keys-using-a-batch-file

Comment: @DavidPostill - The question implies that it does work by reading standard input; the user just didn't know how to simulate the final ENTER.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Now we know (after comments) it is a command line program. The question doesn't specify whether it's a command line or GUI program, hence my initial comment.

Comment: @DavidPostill - the command line was implied when he said that he'd done the redirect and just didn't know how to do the final ENTER.

Comment: @DeltaIV - What is the "FORTRAN error" that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the program appears to read from the standard input stream, adding a final blank line to `batch.txt` should do the trick. If it doesn't, then that last prompt is *not* using standard input, and you'll have to resort to such third-party trickery as SENDKEYS or KEYSTACK.

Comment: Thanks!! I did try to add a blank line before posting to the site, but it didn't work. However, with your reassurance that it ought to work, I tried again and I found that the bloody code then wants an extra input after the ENTER. I didn't understand that before, because the error message was some extremely cryptic error message from Fortran runtime libraries. Now it works!